# How can you assign multiple inputs a single value in Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to assign countries a currency value, but some currencies are used in multiple countries. I know I can just assign them individually for every country but is there a better way of doing it? Something I tried was:

```
rates = { ('England', 'wales'): 'GBP' }
```

where the expected result was:

```
rates['England'] = GBP
rates['wales'] = GBP
```

This doesn't work though. What can I do?

Comment: `rates = {'England': 'GBP', 'Wales': 'GBP'}` is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any syntactic sugar for that use case, but you could use a few methods that aren't too verbose to get the same result:

#### fromkeys

```
# first argument are all keys, second is default value (or None)
rates = dict.fromkeys(('England', 'wales'), 'GBP')
```

#### comprehension

```
rates = {k: 'GBP' for k in ('England', 'wales')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps just flip the two?

```
rates = { 
"GBP": ["England", "Wales"], 
"EUR": ["Germany", "Fance", "Netherlands"] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create lists of countries and add them all in one loop:

```py
GBP_countries=['England', 'wales']
rates = {}
for country in  GBP_countries:
    rates.update({country:'GBP'})
```

Comment: Why use `update` with a singleton `dict`? Just bind the key.